# Scrapy not scraping the whole website even though I find the data with xpath

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I created my first scrapy-project by scraping from https://www.tapology.com. I have a list of links of all the fighters in the world that are ordered by their countries. The scraper opens up the links, scrapes all the fighters on the link, and then moves to the next page for that country or move to the next country if finished.

When I scrape the information of each fighter I get all the data without problem, but when I try to scrape all the rows of their amateur matches or/and pro matches I get nothing. I've tried multiple solutions, but it doesn't work when I scrape it even though I can find the data with XPath.

Link example: https://www.tapology.com/search/mma-fighters-by-nationality/country-no

Fighter example from the link:https://www.tapology.com/fightcenter/fighters/126571-eric-mambo

The part I can scrape from the fighter:
[information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bd7Id.png)

The part I can't scrape from the fighter:
[amateur_record](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fZjsY.png)

I just found out that I can't see the data of his amateur record when I open the page source instead of inspecting the elements.

```
import scrapy
import os
import logging

# , FighterscraperDetailsItem, FighterscraperProRecordItem, FighterscraperAmateurRecordItem
class FighterSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "fighter"
    allowed_domains = ["tapology.com"]
    count = 0
    
    custom_settings = dict(
        DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES={
            "scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware": None,
            "scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry.RetryMiddleware": None,
            "scrapy_fake_useragent.middleware.RandomUserAgentMiddleware": 400,
            "scrapy_fake_useragent.middleware.RetryUserAgentMiddleware": 401,
        },
        FAKEUSERAGENT_PROVIDERS=[
            "scrapy_fake_useragent.providers.FakerProvider",
            "scrapy_fake_useragent.providers.FakeUserAgentProvider",
            "scrapy_fake_useragent.providers.FixedUserAgentProvider",
        ],
    )
    
 
    def start_requests(self):
        with open(os.path.abspath("linkListTest.txt"), "rt") as f:
            urls = [url.strip() for url in f.readlines()]
        
        for url in urls:
            
            yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse_country)


        
    
    def parse_country(self, response):
        print(response.request.headers.get("User-Agent"))
        # hrefs = response.xpath("(//td/a[contains(@href,'/fightcenter/fighters/')])/@href").getall()
        # fixedNames = [s.replace('\\', '').replace('"', '') for s in names]
        
        for href in response.xpath("(//td/a[contains(@href,'/fightcenter/fighters/')])/@href"):
            
            recievedURL = response.urljoin(href.extract())
            yield scrapy.Request(recievedURL, callback = self.parse_fighter_page)
        
        nextPage = response.xpath("(//a[@rel='next'][contains(text(),'Next ›')])[2]/@href").get()
        if nextPage is not None:
            print("***** NEXTPAGE *****")
            newNextPage = response.urljoin(nextPage)
            # print(newNextPage)
            yield scrapy.Request(newNextPage, callback = self.parse_country)
            
        
    def parse_fighter_page(self, response):
       
        lista = []
        item = {}
        # details = ItemLoader(item = FighterscraperDetailsItem(), response = response)

        item['name'] = response.xpath("(//div[@id='stats'])[1]//li[position()=1]//strong[position()=1]/following-sibling::span/text()").get()
        item['fighter_url'] = f"{response.request.url}"
        # fighter.add_xpath('name', "(//div[@id='stats'])[1]//li[position()=1]//strong[position()=1]/following-sibling::span/text()")
        stats = "//div[@id='stats'][1]"
        
        item['details'] = {}
        item['details']['nickname'] = response.xpath(f"{stats}//li/strong[contains(text(), 'Nickname')]/following-sibling::span[position()=1]/text()").get()
        item['details']['record'] = response.xpath(f"{stats}[1]//li[position()=2]//strong[position()=1]/following-sibling::span/text()").get()
        item['details']['age'] = response.xpath("//span[@class='dateToAge'][1]/text()").get()
        item['details']['date_of_birth'] = response.xpath(f"{stats}//li/strong[contains(text(), 'Age')]/following-sibling::span[position()=2]/text()").get()
        item['details']['weight_class'] = response.xpath(f"{stats}//li/strong[contains(text(), 'Weight Class')]/following-sibling::span[position()=1]/text()").get()
        item['details']['born'] = response.xpath(f"{stats}//li/strong[contains(text(), 'Born')]/following-sibling::span[position()=1]/text()").get()
        item['details']['gym'] = response.xpath(f"{stats}//li/strong[contains(text(), 'Affiliation')]/following-sibling::span/a/text()").get()
        
        item['details']['country_code'] = response.xpath("(//div[@class='fighterUpcomingHeader'][1]/h2[@id='flag']/a[contains(@href,'/search/mma-fighters-by-nationality/country-')])/@href").get()
        
        
        # details.add_value('fighter_url', f"{response.request.url}")
        
        # details.add_xpath('nickname',"[1]//li/strong[contains(text(), 'Nickname')]/following-sibling::span[position()=1]/text()")
        # details.add_xpath('record',"[1]//li[position()=2]//strong[position()=1]/following-sibling::span/text()")
        # details.add_xpath('age',"//span[@class='dateToAge'][1]/text()")
        # details.add_xpath('date_of_birth',"//div[@id='stats'][1]//li/strong[contains(text(), 'Age')]/following-sibling::span[position()=2]/text()")
        # details.add_xpath('weight_class',"//div[@id='stats'][1]//li/strong[contains(text(), 'Weight Class')]/following-sibling::span[position()=1]/text()")
        # details.add_xpath('born',"//div[@id='stats'][1]//li/strong[contains(text(), 'Born')]/following-sibling::span[position()=1]/text()")
        # details.add_xpath('country_code',"(//div[@class='fighterUpcomingHeader'][1]/h2[@id='flag']/a[contains(@href,'/search/mma-fighters-by-nationality/country-')])/@href")
        # details.add_xpath('gym',"//div[@id='stats'][1]//li/strong[contains(text(), 'Affiliation')]/following-sibling::span[position()=1]/text()")
        
        item['pro_record'] = {}
        item['amateur_record'] = {}
        
        
        
        for match in response.xpath("//div[@id='react-container'][1]/div[@id='fighterRecord']/section[2]/ul//li/div"): 
            opponent = match.xpath("/div[1]/div[1]/a/text()").extract_first()
            print(opponent)

            # Nothing is printed, this is some of the data that is supposed to be yielded in amateur_record. (Also tried with get() and so on.'
        
        
        yield item
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not getting the results because they are created [dynamically](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/dynamic-content.html).

Learn how to use [scrapy shell](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/shell.html) if you don't know how, it will help you a lot.

If we inspect the page with devtools in the browser under the 'xhr' tab we can see that it gets the data from https://api.tapology.com/v1/internal_fighters/1389126571. So we need to recreate the request with the same number.

```py
scrapy shell "https://www.tapology.com/fightcenter/fighters/126571-eric-mambo"

# Let's first get the correct number so we can create the correct request to the API
In [1]: fid = response.xpath('//meta[@name="fid"]/@content').get()

In [2]: salt = response.xpath('//meta[@name="salt"]/@content').get()

In [3]: file_number = salt + fid

# Now we need to create the headers (I just copied them from devtools).
In [4]: headers = {
   ...: "Accept": "*/*",
   ...: "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
   ...: "Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.5",
   ...: "authorization": "Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJ1c2VyIjoiaW50ZXJuYWxfYXBpIiwiZXhwIjoyNTM3NjU0N
   ...: DAwfQ.C1E9hhkQOH7XrfZ5c7aTYS4CKN3ACkJ1nvgvx2v10YY",
   ...: "Cache-Control": "no-cache",
   ...: "Connection": "keep-alive",
   ...: "content-type": "application/vnd.api+json",
   ...: "DNT": "1",
   ...: "Host": "api.tapology.com",
   ...: "Origin": "https://www.tapology.com",
   ...: "Pragma": "no-cache",
   ...: "Referer": "https://www.tapology.com/",
   ...: "Sec-Fetch-Dest": "empty",
   ...: "Sec-Fetch-Mode": "cors",
   ...: "Sec-Fetch-Site": "same-site",
   ...: "Sec-GPC": "1",
   ...: "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.169 Safari/537.36"
   ...: }

# create the request and fetch it
In [5]: req = scrapy.Request(url=f"https://api.tapology.com/v1/internal_fighters/{file_number}", headers=headers)

In [6]: fetch(req)
[scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://api.tapology.com/v1/internal_fighters/138931242> (referer: https://www.tapology.com/)

# we got a json file, let's parse it (you can check it out by printing it or type view(response) to open it)

In [7]: json_data = response.json()
In [8]: for fighter in json_data['included']:
   ...:     print(fighter['id'])
   ...:     print(fighter['attributes']['opponent_fighter_name'])
   ...:
1170431
Greg Fischer
931909
Mohammad Alavi
879994
Kenta Takizawa
846160
Rodney Mondala
764333
Scott MacGregor
674056
Hiroyuki Oshiro
650257
Luke Catubig
600477
Josh Branham
534279
Won Jun Jang
458178
Rilley Dutro
427351
Jerome Cruz
356615
Kwan Ho Kwak
306251
Mark Abelardo
356662
Vince Masga
256096
Trevin Jones
175233
Ian Dela Cuesta
129057
Jung Hoon Ko
129499
Vince Pua
656653
John Paul Mendiola
129503
Carlos Tiongson
```

**EDIT:**

To get the correct results you need to add headers when you request the fighters page, example:

```py
In [1]: req = scrapy.Request(url = 'https://www.tapology.com/fightcenter/fighters/126571-eric-mambo')

In [2]: fetch(req)
[scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
[scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.tapology.com/fightcenter/fighters/126571-eric-mambo> (referer: None)

In [3]: view(response)
Out[3]: True
```

We get the page:
[image]
even though we wanted another page.

With headers:

```py
In [4]: headers = {
   ...: "Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8",
   ...: "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
   ...: "Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.5",
   ...: "Cache-Control": "no-cache",
   ...: "Connection": "keep-alive",
   ...: "DNT": "1",
   ...: "Host": "www.tapology.com",
   ...: "Pragma": "no-cache",
   ...: "Referer": "https://www.tapology.com/search?term=eric+mambo",
   ...: "Sec-Fetch-Dest": "document",
   ...: "Sec-Fetch-Mode": "navigate",
   ...: "Sec-Fetch-Site": "same-origin",
   ...: "Sec-Fetch-User": "?1",
   ...: "Sec-GPC": "1",
   ...: "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests": "1",
   ...: "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.372
   ...: 9.169 Safari/537.36"
   ...: }

In [5]: req = scrapy.Request(url = 'https://www.tapology.com/fightcenter/fighters/126571-eric-mambo', headers=headers)

In [6]: fetch(req)
[scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.tapology.com/fightcenter/fighters/126571-eric-mambo> (referer: https://www.tapology.com/search?term=eric+mambo)

In [7]: view(response)
Out[7]: True
```

We get the page we wanted:
[image]

Copy your headers, and add them to the the page requests, for example `yield scrapy.Request(recievedURL, callback=self.parse_fighter_page, headers=headers)`, and for the api use the headers I used.

**EDIT 2:**

```py
import scrapy
import os
import logging

# , FighterscraperDetailsItem, FighterscraperProRecordItem, FighterscraperAmateurRecordItem
class FighterSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "fighter"
    allowed_domains = ["tapology.com"]
    count = 0

    custom_settings = dict(
        DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES={
            "scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware": None,
            "scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry.RetryMiddleware": None,
            "scrapy_fake_useragent.middleware.RandomUserAgentMiddleware": 400,
            "scrapy_fake_useragent.middleware.RetryUserAgentMiddleware": 401,
        },
        FAKEUSERAGENT_PROVIDERS=[
            "scrapy_fake_useragent.providers.FakerProvider",
            "scrapy_fake_useragent.providers.FakeUserAgentProvider",
            "scrapy_fake_useragent.providers.FixedUserAgentProvider",
        ],
    )

    headers = {
        "Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8",
        "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
        "Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.5",
        "Cache-Control": "no-cache",
        "Connection": "keep-alive",
        "DNT": "1",
        "Host": "www.tapology.com",
        "Pragma": "no-cache",
        "Sec-Fetch-Dest": "document",
        "Sec-Fetch-Mode": "navigate",
        "Sec-Fetch-Site": "none",
        "Sec-Fetch-User": "?1",
        "Sec-GPC": "1",
        "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests": "1",
        "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.169 Safari/537.36"
    }

    api_headers = {
        "Accept": "*/*",
        "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
        "Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.5",
        "authorization": "Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJ1c2VyIjoiaW50ZXJuYWxfYXBpIiwiZXhwIjoyNTM3NjU0NDAwfQ.C1E9hhkQOH7XrfZ5c7aTYS4CKN3ACkJ1nvgvx2v10YY",
        "Cache-Control": "no-cache",
        "Connection": "keep-alive",
        "content-type": "application/vnd.api+json",
        "DNT": "1",
        "Host": "api.tapology.com",
        "Origin": "https://www.tapology.com",
        "Pragma": "no-cache",
        "Referer": "https://www.tapology.com/",
        "Sec-Fetch-Dest": "empty",
        "Sec-Fetch-Mode": "cors",
        "Sec-Fetch-Site": "same-site",
        "Sec-GPC": "1",
        "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.169 Safari/537.36"
    }

    def start_requests(self):
        with open(os.path.abspath("linkListTest.txt"), "rt") as f:
            urls = [url.strip() for url in f.readlines()]

        for url in urls:
            yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse_country)

    def parse_country(self, response):
        print(response.request.headers.get("User-Agent"))
        # hrefs = response.xpath("(//td/a[contains(@href,'/fightcenter/fighters/')])/@href").getall()
        # fixedNames = [s.replace('\\', '').replace('"', '') for s in names]

        for href in response.xpath("(//td/a[contains(@href,'/fightcenter/fighters/')])/@href"):
            recievedURL = response.urljoin(href.extract())
            yield scrapy.Request(recievedURL, callback=self.parse_fighter_page, headers=self.headers)

        nextPage = response.xpath("(//a[@rel='next'][contains(text(),'Next ›')])[2]/@href").get()
        if nextPage is not None:
            print("***** NEXTPAGE *****")
            newNextPage = response.urljoin(nextPage)
            # print(newNextPage)
            yield scrapy.Request(newNextPage, callback=self.parse_country, headers=self.headers)

    def parse_fighter_page(self, response):
        lista = []
        item = {}
        # details = ItemLoader(item = FighterscraperDetailsItem(), response = response)

        item['name'] = response.xpath("(//div[@id='stats'])[1]//li[position()=1]//strong[position()=1]/following-sibling::span/text()").get()
        item['fighter_url'] = f"{response.request.url}"
        # fighter.add_xpath('name', "(//div[@id='stats'])[1]//li[position()=1]//strong[position()=1]/following-sibling::span/text()")
        stats = "//div[@id='stats'][1]"

        item['details'] = {}
        item['details']['nickname'] = response.xpath(f"{stats}//li/strong[contains(text(), 'Nickname')]/following-sibling::span[position()=1]/text()").get()
        item['details']['record'] = response.xpath(f"{stats}[1]//li[position()=2]//strong[position()=1]/following-sibling::span/text()").get()
        item['details']['age'] = response.xpath("//span[@class='dateToAge'][1]/text()").get()
        item['details']['date_of_birth'] = response.xpath(f"{stats}//li/strong[contains(text(), 'Age')]/following-sibling::span[position()=2]/text()").get()
        item['details']['weight_class'] = response.xpath(f"{stats}//li/strong[contains(text(), 'Weight Class')]/following-sibling::span[position()=1]/text()").get()
        item['details']['born'] = response.xpath(f"{stats}//li/strong[contains(text(), 'Born')]/following-sibling::span[position()=1]/text()").get()
        item['details']['gym'] = response.xpath(f"{stats}//li/strong[contains(text(), 'Affiliation')]/following-sibling::span/a/text()").get()

        item['details']['country_code'] = response.xpath("(//div[@class='fighterUpcomingHeader'][1]/h2[@id='flag']/a[contains(@href,'/search/mma-fighters-by-nationality/country-')])/@href").get()


        # details.add_value('fighter_url', f"{response.request.url}")

        # details.add_xpath('nickname',"[1]//li/strong[contains(text(), 'Nickname')]/following-sibling::span[position()=1]/text()")
        # details.add_xpath('record',"[1]//li[position()=2]//strong[position()=1]/following-sibling::span/text()")
        # details.add_xpath('age',"//span[@class='dateToAge'][1]/text()")
        # details.add_xpath('date_of_birth',"//div[@id='stats'][1]//li/strong[contains(text(), 'Age')]/following-sibling::span[position()=2]/text()")
        # details.add_xpath('weight_class',"//div[@id='stats'][1]//li/strong[contains(text(), 'Weight Class')]/following-sibling::span[position()=1]/text()")
        # details.add_xpath('born',"//div[@id='stats'][1]//li/strong[contains(text(), 'Born')]/following-sibling::span[position()=1]/text()")
        # details.add_xpath('country_code',"(//div[@class='fighterUpcomingHeader'][1]/h2[@id='flag']/a[contains(@href,'/search/mma-fighters-by-nationality/country-')])/@href")
        # details.add_xpath('gym',"//div[@id='stats'][1]//li/strong[contains(text(), 'Affiliation')]/following-sibling::span[position()=1]/text()")

        item['pro_record'] = {}
        item['amateur_record'] = {}

        fid = response.xpath('//meta[@name="fid"]/@content').get()
        salt = response.xpath('//meta[@name="salt"]/@content').get()
        file_number = salt + fid

        yield scrapy.Request(url=f"https://api.tapology.com/v1/internal_fighters/{file_number}",
                             headers=self.api_headers,
                             callback=self.parse_api, meta={'item': item})

    def parse_api(self, response):
        json_data = response.json()
        api_data = []
        for fighter in json_data['included']:
            opponent_id = fighter['id']
            opponent_name = fighter['attributes']['opponent_fighter_name']
            api_data.append({'id': opponent_id, 'opponent_name': opponent_name})

        item = response.meta['item']
        item['opponent'] = api_data
        yield item
```

Comment: YESS!! Thank you. It frikkin worked. The code for the fighter is also in the original link https://www.tapology.com/fightcenter/fighters/126571-eric-mambo (126571).

Comment: Or not. The data I get back isn't the data associated with the fighter. If you check the opponents you printed out, it isn't right. I can see the full JSON file in the preview when I select Network in my browser, but the data that gets returned are different @SuperUser

Comment: @vebbis See the edit. If it works for you please accept the answer, and if it doesn't work let me know please.

Comment: It didn't work since if you use the edited answer I only get the page in source format, and then his amateur fights aren't available, and when I do the first approach with the API endpoint (I also added the headers) I can see his data in the JSON file, but when I extract I get the wrong data. You can see it in your first example when you use the API endpoint, since Solom Simon is the name you are supposed to get when you extract from the JSON file, but you get Greg Fischer which is an opponent he has never fought and isn't on his page. The same goes for Mohammad Alavi and so on. @SuperUser

Comment: @vebbis Can you please provide a couple of links from "linkListTest.txt" so I could test it with your code?

Comment: https://www.tapology.com/search/mma-fighters-by-nationality/country-no https://www.tapology.com/search/mma-fighters-by-nationality/country-se @SuperUser

Comment: @vebbis I used what I said in edit1 and implemented it in edit2. I checked 3 different pages and everything was correct. Hope it's OK now.

Comment: Awesome solution. Thank you! I think it was due to some of my settings it didn't run properly. I started a new project with the exact same spider, and it works smoothly now. @SuperUser

Answer (score -1):

You can extract fighter information with this code also please check:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.utils.response import open_in_browser
import urllib.parse
class FighterinfoSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'fighter'
    allowed_domains = ['tapology.com']
    start_urls = ['https://www.tapology.com/search']

    def parse(self, response):
        # extract countrywise figher list
        fighters_by_nationality = response.xpath('//div[@class="siteSearchFightersByNationality"]/dd/a/@href').getall()
        for link in fighters_by_nationality:
            yield response.follow(link, callback = self.parse_fighter_list_by_country)
    
    

    def parse_fighter_list_by_country(self,response):
        # extract fighter list
        all_fighter_links = response.xpath('//table[@class="siteSearchResults"]/tr/td/a/@href').getall()

        for individual_fighter in all_fighter_links:
            url = urllib.parse.urljoin('https://www.tapology.com',individual_fighter)
            yield scrapy.Request(url,callback=self.parse_fighter_page)
        next_page = response.xpath('//span[@class="next"]/a/@href').get()
        if next_page:
            yield response.follow(next_page, callback = self.parse_fighter_list_by_country)

    def parse_fighter_page(self, response):
        # extract fighter information
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. It's his amateur record that I can't scrape, not the rest of the information from his page